# Как поменять местами элементы массива относительно середины

Tags: java

Есть массив `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, нужно привести его к виду `[5,6,7,4,1,2,3]`.

Как я понимаю, это делается в 2 цикла: в одном бежим от `i = 0` до середины массива (`middleArray`) и во втором от `j = middleArray + 1` до конца. Сохраняем значение `x = arr[i]`, затем `arr[i] = arr[j]`, `затем arr[j] = x`. Вот так идёт ход моих мыслей. Правильно ли это будет?

Comment: В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    if (array.length < 2) return;

    //находим середину массива
    int border = (array.length + 1) / 2;

    //меняем местами элементы массива
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++){
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[border + i];
        array[border + i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо! достаточно было просто на словах алгоритм описать, но так тоже хорошо =)